# Передать значения в WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, парсер

Есть парсер динамики курса валют от ЦБ

```
# Базовый URL скрипта на cbr.ru
$scripturl = 'http://www.cbr.ru/scripts/XML_dynamic.asp';

# Начальная дата для запроса  (сегодня - 2 дня)
$date_1=date('d/m/Y', time()-172800);

# Конечная дата (чтобы учитывать завтра добавьте параметр time()+86400)
$date_2=date('d/m/Y');

# Таким образом, мы получим данные либо за 2, либо за 3 последних дня.
# За 2 - если на "сегодня" курс еще не выставили, иначе - за 3

# Код валюты в архиве данных cbr.ru
$currency_code='R01235';

# URL для запроса данных
$requrl = "{$scripturl}?date_req1={$date_1}&date_req2={$date_2}&VAL_NM_RQ={$currency_code}";

$doc = file($requrl);
$doc = implode($doc, '');

# инициализируем массив
$r = array();

# ищем <ValCurs>...</ValCurs>
if(preg_match("/<ValCurs.*?>(.*?)<\/ValCurs>/is", $doc, $m))
    # а потом ищем все вхождения <Record>...</Record>
    preg_match_all("/<Record(.*?)>(.*?)<\/Record>/is", $m[1], $r, PREG_SET_ORDER);

$m = array();   # его уже использовали, реинициализируем
$d = array();   # этот тоже проинициализируем

# Сканируем на предмет самых нужных цифр
for($i=0; $i<count($r); $i++) {
    if(preg_match("/Date=\"(\d{2})\.(\d{2})\.(\d{4})\"/is", $r[$i][1],$m)) {
        $dv = "{$m[1]}/{$m[2]}/{$m[3]}"; # Приводим дату в норм. вид
        if(preg_match("/<Nominal>(.*?)<\/Nominal>.*?<Value>(.*?)<\/Value>/is", $r[$i][2], $m)) {
            $m[2] = preg_replace("/,/",".",$m[2]);
            $d[] = array($dv, $m[1], $m[2]);
            }
        }
    }

$last = array_pop($d);              # последний известный день
$prev = array_pop($d);              # предпосл. известный день
$date = $last[0];               # отображаемая дата
$rate = sprintf("%.2f",$last[2]);       # отображаемый курс
# отображаемое изменение курса, например, "+0.02"
$delta = (($last[2]>$prev[2])?"+":"").sprintf("%.2f",$last[2]-$prev[2]);
```

Как лучше всего передать значения переменных $date, $rate, $delta в вордпресс для дальнейшего использования? Сам скрипт находится в корне сайта и запускается раз в сутки по крону.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проще всего передать данные в WordPress через опцию. Добавьте в конец своего скрипта

```
// Load WP.
require_once 'wp-load.php';

update_option( 'my_cb_data', [ $date, $rate, $delta ] );
```

И тогда на сайте WordPress в нужном шаблоне:

```
$my_cb_data = get_option( 'my_cb_data' );

$date  = $my_cb_data[0];
$rate  = $my_cb_data[1];
$delta = $my_cb_data[2];
```

Comment: где то читал что подключать wp-load.php не совсем правильно (не безопастно что ли) правда там он подключался 
`require($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/wp-load.php');`

Comment: Не читайте на ночь советских газет. Это единственно  правильный способ загрузки ядра WordPress. И сам WP так себя загружает.